# How to use output of one command as input in another command

Tags: rhel, sort

I made a copy of all the backups made on Wed of every week
The time stamp of each file is not sorted but the day is Wednesday of every file

Now, I need to sort each file based on time Stamp e.g if date is 1-May then it should first display the backup files of 1-May then it should display the files of 8-May

I used this command but of course it is slapping me with error

```
sort $(cat /home/emerg/Wedbackup.txt)
```

Error is

```
sort: invalid option -- w
```

As i don't know how to use the output of one command as input of 2nd command. I need advice how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no need to use cat in this case:

```
sort /home/emerg/Wedbackup.txt
```

The problem with your example is that your file is being passed as *the command line* to sort, which is not what you want. For example, if this was your file:

```
foo bar
baz qux
wibble wobble
```

The arguments would look like this:

```
sort foo bar baz qux wibble wobble
```

This is not what you want. What you actually want is to pass the file to `sort` on stdin, which can be done like this:

```
sort < /home/emerg/Wedbackup.txt
```

This is more generalisable, as taking a filename as an argument is specific to `sort`, and is not a universal convention.

In the case of sort, you should prefer to pass the filename as an argument rather than on stdin, as it allows seeking on the file, which can improve sorting efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

You should use pipe, like this:

```
cat /home/emerg/Wedbackup.txt | sort
```

Comment: [UUOC](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)